# Symfony2 doctrine create query

Tags: php, sql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I have 3 Entities:
Blog:

```
class Blog {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
//...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProductTag", inversedBy="blogs", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="blog_product_tag",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $product_tags;
//...
}
```

ProductTag

```
class ProductTag {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
//...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="blogs", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $blogs;
//...
}
```

Product

```
class Product {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
//...


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProductTag", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_product_tag",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $product_tags;
//...
}
```

And i want to make query which will give me blogs which are corresponded to product_tags which are corresponded to products:

```
SELECT b . * 
FROM  `product` p
JOIN product_product_tag ppt ON ( p.id = ppt.product_id ) 
JOIN product_tag pt ON ( ppt.product_tag_id = pt.id ) 
JOIN blog_product_tag bpt ON ( pt.id = bpt.product_tag_id ) 
JOIN blog b ON ( bpt.blog_id = b.id ) 
WHERE p.id =5
```

How to do that? I need to use this to knp_paginator :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution. The problem was that I had created one directional relation in blog - product_tag and product - product_tag entities.
Based on the information here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html I have changed definition of ProductTag entity as fallow:

```
//...
class ProductTag {
//...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="product_tags", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $blogs;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="product_tags", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $products;
//...
```

And it allowed me to create in BlogRepository following method:

```
public function getRelatedBlogsByProduct(Product $product) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->select('b')
            ->join('b.product_tags', 'pt')
            ->join('pt.products', 'p')
            ->where('p.id = :product_id')
            ->setParameter('product_id', $product->getId())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

And it is generating following SQL:

```
SELECT b0_.id AS id0, b0_.title AS title1, b0_.author AS author2, b0_.blog AS blog3, b0_.image AS image4, b0_.created AS created5, b0_.updated AS updated6, b0_.published AS published7, b0_.is_homepage_slider AS is_homepage_slider8, b0_.is_category_slider AS is_category_slider9, b0_.is_breaking_news AS is_breaking_news10, b0_.category_id AS category_id11 FROM blog b0_ INNER JOIN blog_product_tag b2_ ON b0_.id = b2_.blog_id INNER JOIN product_tag p1_ ON p1_.id = b2_.product_tag_id INNER JOIN product_product_tag p4_ ON p1_.id = p4_.product_tag_id INNER JOIN Product p3_ ON p3_.id = p4_.product_id WHERE p3_.id = 2
```

Which in 1 SQL is getting all blogs I wanted.

Thank you Ajeet for help it helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

i do't understand query too much , but you can also use magic method to fetch blogs as given below ..

```
         $blogs = array();
         $product = $em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product')->find($id);
         $productTags = $product->getProductTags();
         foreach($productTags as $productTag){
            $blogs = $productTag->getBlogs();
         }
        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $blogs,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
         );

         return array(
                'pagination' => $pagination,
         );
```

and in your twig file

```
       {% for blog in pagination %}
          {% if loop.last %}
             {{ blog.text }}
          {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}

        {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
```

Anyway if your query is correct you can also do as below :

```
          $dql = SELECT b . * 
                 FROM  `product` p
                 JOIN product_product_tag ppt ON ( p.id = ppt.product_id ) 
                 JOIN product_tag pt ON ( ppt.product_tag_id = pt.id ) 
                 JOIN blog_product_tag bpt ON ( pt.id = bpt.product_tag_id ) 
                 JOIN blog b ON ( bpt.blog_id = b.id ) 
                 WHERE p.id =$id;
          $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
          $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
          $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
                $query,
                $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
                10/*limit per page*/
               );

          return array(
                   'pagination' => $pagination,
               );
```

and in twig file will be remained as i described above ..

Comment: Unfortunately the SQL is not working. 
When I am using the SQL way I am getting the "No such class error" corresponding to the product. So I changed the product table in SQL to BundleName:Product and that's fine however I don't have entity for joining table (product_product_tag and blog_product_tag). 
Always I can loop through objects however it is not efective way. What if i will have thousend of product_tags and thousend of blogs? Then iterationg through all of them will take ages! It should be possible to get results just from the SQL server.

Comment: You mean by iterating through objects and geting objects from objects? This is very not effective. Each getter will probably send another SQL query to database. So there ill be 1 SQL for getting product then 1 SQL to getproduct_tags and for each proguct tag 1 SQL to get blogs related to this tag. For 10 product_tags it is 1+1+10 = 12 queries! And it is possible to get in 1 query.